# Need generic form to allow my friend to talk with my son's school

Tags: ferpa

I told the principal I wanted my friend to be able to communicate with the school regarding my son. She gave me a form to sign. I filled it out and signed it. (Unfortunately I don't have a copy.) The school is somehow not satisfied and is not willing to talk with my friend or provide her with copies of documents.

Is there a generic form I can download for this? I'd like to start again, this time making a copy before I give it to them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do an internet search for "school power of attorney" you will get some samples, perhaps even one for your state.

You might see this one from Kentucky as the first hit.

[image]